# Bmesh: How to select newly created vertices?

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh, knife-tool

I'm running bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project(cut_through=True) using an Edge to Slice a mesh.

Next I want to select newly created Edge loop and remove all other vertices. I'm thinking of capturing two states: bmesh before cut & after cut. Compare index of verts and leave only verts that are in 'new index'.

Am I thinking of this process correctly?

[image]